# How do I write scikit-learn dataset to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I can load a data set from `scikit-learn` using

```
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.load_boston()
print(data)
```

What I'd like to do is write this data set to a flat file (`.csv`)

Using the `open()` function,

```
f = open('boston.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(data))
```

works, but includes the description of the data set.

I'm wondering if there is some way that I can generate a simple `.csv` with headers from this Bunch object so I can move it around and use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data = datasets.load_boston()` will generate a dictionary. In order to write the data to a `.csv` file you need the actual data `data['data']` and the columns `data['feature_names']`. You can use these in order to generate a pandas dataframe and then use `to_csv()` in order to write the data to a file:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd 

data = datasets.load_boston()
print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data['data'], columns = data['feature_names'])
df.to_csv('boston.txt', sep = ',', index = False)
```

and the output `boston.txt` should be:

```
CRIM,ZN,INDUS,CHAS,NOX,RM,AGE,DIS,RAD,TAX,PTRATIO,B,LSTAT
0.00632,18.0,2.31,0.0,0.538,6.575,65.2,4.09,1.0,296.0,15.3,396.9,4.98
0.02731,0.0,7.07,0.0,0.469,6.421,78.9,4.9671,2.0,242.0,17.8,396.9,9.14
0.02729,0.0,7.07,0.0,0.469,7.185,61.1,4.9671,2.0,242.0,17.8,392.83,4.03
...
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various toy datasets in scikit-learn such as **Iris** and **Boston** datasets. Let's load **Boston** dataset:

```
from sklearn import datasets
boston = datasets.load_boston()
```

What type of object is this? If we examine its type, we see that this is a scikit-learn **Bunch** object.

```
print(type(boston))
```

Output:

```
<class 'sklearn.utils.Bunch'>
```

A scikit-learn **Bunch** object is a kind of dictionary. So, we should treat it as such. We can use dictionary methods. Let's look at the keys:

```
print(boston.keys())
```

output:

```
dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'feature_names', 'DESCR', 'filename'])
```

Here we are interested in **data**, **feature_names** and **target** keys. We will import **pandas** module and use these keys to create a pandas **DataFrame**.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=boston['data'], columns=boston['feature_names'])
```

We should also add the target variable to the DataFrame. Target variable is what we try to predict. We should learn the target variable's name. It is written in the **"DESCR"**. We can
`print(boston["DESCR"])` and read the full description of the dataset.

In the description we see that the name of the target variable is *MEDV*. Now, we can add the target variable to the DataFrame:

```
df['MEDV'] = boston['target']
```

There is only one step left. We are exporting the DataFrame to a csv file without index numbers:

```
df.to_csv("scikit_learn_boston_dataset.csv", index=False)
```

**BONUS**: **Iris** dataset has additional parameters that we can utilize ([look at here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html#sklearn.datasets.load_iris)). Following code automatically creates the DataFrame with the target variable included:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris(as_frame=True)
df = iris["frame"]
```

**Note**: If we `print(iris.keys())`, we can see the **'frame'** key:

```
dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'frame', 'target_names', 'DESCR', 'feature_names', 'filename'])
```

**BONUS2**: If we `print(boston["filename"])` or `print(iris["filename"])`, we can see the physical locations of the csv files of these datasets. For instance:

```
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\data\boston_house_prices.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to modify the reply by adding that you should probably include the target variable--"MV"--as well. Added an additional line below:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd 

data = datasets.load_boston()
print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data['data'], columns = data['feature_names'])

**df['MV'] = data['target']**

df.to_csv('boston.txt', sep = ',', index = False)
```