# How to save a random dataset for a data science interview test

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am looking into scikit-learn in order to produce some datasets for a data science interview. This is a new role for us.

I am looking into

```
sklearn.datasets.make_regression
```

And have this beginning

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn import linear_model, datasets


n_samples = 1000
n_outliers = 50


X, y, coef = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=10,
                                      n_informative=1, noise=10,
                                      coef=True, random_state=0)
array = np.array(list(zip(X, y)))

array.tofile('yourfile.txt',sep=",",format="%s")
```

What I have now is doing something unexpected.

> [-0.34791215  1.23029068 -0.38732682  0.37816252  1.20237985
>   -0.30230275  -1.98079647  0.15634897  0.15494743 -0.88778575],-1.2020466345326724,[-0.50965218 -1.25279536 -1.61389785 -1.42001794  0.77749036 -0.21274028
>     1.9507754  -0.4380743  -1.04855297 -1.70627019],-5.471683206809487,[ 2.26975462  0.04575852  1.53277921  0.6536186  -0.18718385  1.46935877  -0.74216502 -1.45436567 -2.55298982  0.8644362 ],-43.65842091125963,[ 0.44386323  1.49407907  0.3130677   1.45427351 -0.20515826 -0.85409574
>     0.12167502  0.33367433  0.14404357  0.76103773],-5.470350015809552,[ 1.86755799  0.95008842 -0.10321885  0.40015721 -0.15135721  0.4105985
>     2.2408932  -0.97727788  1.76405235  0.97873798],31.156701729506093

But how do I output this to a human-readable CSV file?

And then how to import it from this CSV so that I can create a boilerplate setup for the candidate to go through during a pairing test?

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346510/how-do-i-write-scikit-learn-dataset-to-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

```
np.save('data.npy', X)
X = np.load('data.npy')
```

Edit: This seems better

```
np.savez('mat.npz',X=X,y=y,coeff=coef)
data = np.load('mat.npz')
data['X']
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is helping orient me. I edited the question to indicate that I would like a human-readable file.